# google cloud platform Cloud locations for Kubernetes(GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

Do you know where to look for information, regarding setting up for distributing containers and volumes into locations?

The following link, states that Kubernetes Engine is an available product for locations:

***"Products available by location"***

***"Deploy resources in specific zones, regions and multi-regions."***

https://cloud.google.com/about/locations

Comment: you can check volume location in console to disk and regarding setting up a cluster in for multi-region we can choose that during settingup cluster.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the loadbalancer will hit the node closest to the region/Zone - if I configure a container to a node(nodeSelector: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/)

Comment: i am not 100% sure but maybe GKE ingress supporting regional load balancing however not sure regarding ingress nginx.

Comment: Right, good direction - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add more details to what @Harsh Manvar mentioned and to answer your question. The global load balancing offerings will route traffic to the backend instances in the zone closest to the client. That said there are some [scenarios](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#traffic_flow_within_a_region) where this may not occur 100% of the time.

In general users traffic is directed to a single IP address. Points of Presence (PoPs) terminate traffic as near as possible to your users and direct load-balanced traffic to the closest healthy backend that has capacity. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/locations)

‘nodeselector’ basically forces a Pod to run only on Nodes in that node pool. Depending on the resource availability, traffic will be sent from the Load balancer to the aforementioned nodes where you attached the [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#step-two-add-a-nodeselector-field-to-your-pod-configuration).

I hope this helps